# Ionic 2. Contenido ngFor en segments

Tags: ionic2

Buenas, tengo un problema a la hora de cargar el contenido de diferentes segments en mi página. Os muestro primero el código en el que creo los segmentos y su contenido.

```
<div padding>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="accion">
    <ion-segment-button value="crear">
      Crear zona
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="modificar">
      Modificar zona
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</div>

<ion-card center *ngIf="accion=='crear'">
  <ion-card-content>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating> Nombre del area: </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nombreArea"> </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <label>Dispositivo asociado:</label>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let dispositivo2 of dispositivosAnadir">
            <ion-label> {{dispositivo2.name}} </ion-label>
              <ion-checkbox color="royal" [(ngModel)]="dispositivo2.selected" value="dispositivo2.value"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <div padding>
      <button (click)="marcarTodos()" ion-button icon-left color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon> Marcar todos 
      </button>
      <button (click)="desmarcarTodos()" ion-button icon-left color="royal"> 
        <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon> Desmarcar todos 
      </button>
    </div>

    <div padding>
      <button (click)="startShape()" [disabled]="pintando" ion-button icon-left color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="brush"></ion-icon> Pintar zona
      </button>
      <button (click)="endShape()" [disabled]="!pintando" ion-button icon-left color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="flag"></ion-icon> Fin pintar zona
      </button>
      <button (click)="cancelShape()" [disabled]="!pintando" ion-button icon-left color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon> Cancelar
      </button>
    </div>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>


<ion-card center *ngIf="accion=='modificar'">
  <ion-card-content>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Seleccionar zona: </ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="zonasSelector.seleccionada" (ionChange)="cambioZonaSeleccionada()">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let zona of zonasSelector.array" [value]="zona.value">{{zona.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let dispositivo of dispositivosModificar">
            <ion-label> {{dispositivo.name}} </ion-label>
              <ion-checkbox color="royal" [(ngModel)]="dispositivo.selected" value="dispositivo.value" [disabled]="zonasSelector.seleccionada == null"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <div padding>
      <button ion-button icon-left (click)="modificarZona()" [disabled]="zonasSelector.seleccionada == null" color="royal"> 
        <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon> Modificar 
      </button>
      <button ion-button icon-left (click)="showConfirmDelete()" [disabled]="zonasSelector.seleccionada == null" color="royal"> 
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon> Eliminar
      </button>
    </div>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Antes de tenerlo así, lo tenía todo junto en la página, sin separación y funcionaba perfectamente. Al separar el contenido por segments me aparece un problema. En el contenido de ambos segments tengo un ngFor que permite mostrar un conjunto de checkboxs. La primera vez que cargo la página, aparece el contenido del segment por defecto sin problemas, pero si cambio de segment el conjunto de checkboxs no vuelve a aparecer.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué pasa eso?

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le interesa he conseguido solucionarlo sacando la ion-list donde tengo el ng-for fuera de la ion-list donde se engloba, es decir, quedando la ion-list del ng-for simplemente dentro de ion-content.

```
<!-- SEGMENTOS -->
<div padding>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="accion">
    <ion-segment-button value="crear">
      Crear zona
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="modificar">
      Modificar zona
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</div>


<!-- CREAR ZONA -->
<ion-card center *ngIf="accion=='crear'">
  <ion-card-content>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating> Nombre del area: </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nombreArea"> </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <div padding>
      <label>Dispositivo asociado:</label>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let dispositivo2 of dispositivosAnadir">
          <ion-label> {{dispositivo2.name}} </ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox color="royal" [(ngModel)]="dispositivo2.selected" value="dispositivo2.value"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </div>

    <div padding>
      <button (click)="marcarTodos()" ion-button icon-left color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon> Marcar todos 
      </button>
      <button (click)="desmarcarTodos()" ion-button icon-left color="royal"> 
        <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon> Desmarcar todos 
      </button>
    </div>

    <div padding>
      <button (click)="startShape()" [disabled]="pintando" ion-button icon-left color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="brush"></ion-icon> Pintar zona
      </button>
      <button (click)="endShape()" [disabled]="!pintando" ion-button icon-left color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="flag"></ion-icon> Fin pintar zona
      </button>
      <button (click)="cancelShape()" [disabled]="!pintando" ion-button icon-left color="royal">
        <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon> Cancelar
      </button>
    </div>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>


<!-- MODIFICAR ZONA -->
<ion-card center *ngIf="accion=='modificar'">
  <ion-card-content>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Seleccionar zona: </ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="zonasSelector.seleccionada" (ionChange)="cambioZonaSeleccionada()">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let zona of zonasSelector.array" [value]="zona.value">{{zona.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let dispositivo of dispositivosModificar">
        <ion-label> {{dispositivo.name}} </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox color="royal" [(ngModel)]="dispositivo.selected" value="dispositivo.value" [disabled]="zonasSelector.seleccionada == null"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <div padding *ngIf="accion=='modificar'">
      <button ion-button icon-left (click)="modificarZona()" [disabled]="zonasSelector.seleccionada == null" color="royal"> 
        <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon> Modificar 
      </button>
      <button ion-button icon-left (click)="showConfirmDelete()" [disabled]="zonasSelector.seleccionada == null" color="royal"> 
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon> Eliminar
      </button>
    </div>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte me ayuda a ver un error en mis segments